# figuring out y-intercept with a given slope in python

Tags: python, math, geometry

I'm trying to compute the intercept of a slope but I can't all of my test units to work. I get the first test units to work but the last one I'm having some trouble. Can someone help me find the error?

```
def test(actual, expected):
    """ Compare the actual to the expected value,
        and print a suitable message.
    """
    import sys
    linenum = sys._getframe(1).f_lineno   # get the caller's line number.
    if (expected == actual):
        msg = "Test on line {0} passed.".format(linenum)
    else:
        msg = ("Test on line {0} failed. Expected '{1}', but got '{2}'."
                                 . format(linenum, expected, actual))
    print(msg)

def slope (x1, y1, x2, y2):
    x2 = (x2 - x1)
    y2 = (y2 - y1)

    m = (y2/x2)
    return m

def intercept(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    m = slope(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    b = y2 - (m*x2)
    return b 


def test_suite():
    test(intercept(1, 6, 3, 12), 3.0)
    test(intercept(6, 1, 1, 6), 7.0)
    test(intercept(4, 6, 12, 8), 5.0)






test_suite()
```

Comment: See also: http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are being given a clue by the test output: `Expected '5.0', but got '8'.` Note that the expected value is a floating point number, but the actual result is an integer.

A quick fix is to change your `slope` function to:

```
def slope (x1, y1, x2, y2):
    x2 = (x2 - x1)
    y2 = (y2 - y1)

    m = (1.0*y2/x2)
    return m
```

Another fix would be to switch to Python 3, or add `from __future__ import division` to the top of your .py file. In Python 3, division casts to floating point by default. See [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I had to put an ".0" for it to be a floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing integer values, so the '/' operator defaults to integer division. Changing `slope` suffices:

```
def slope (x1, y1, x2, y2):
    x2 = float(x2 - x1)
    y2 = float(y2 - y1)

    m = (y2/x2)
    return m
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework to me. Try going through the final testcase by hand and printing the values out to see if you get the same.

e.g: replace your slope function with the following

```
def slope (x1, y1, x2, y2):
    x2 = (x2 - x1)
    y2 = (y2 - y1)
    print y2,x2
    m = (y2/x2)
    print m
    print 1.0*y2/x2
    return 1.0*y2/x2
```